# VHDL Delay before lighting led

Tags: vhdl, delay, clock, led

I want to make a simple vhdl code which makes a delay of 20 sec before a led will be ON. i used a signal counter to make the delay of the 20 sec, but i've noticed to very strange thing, if i am not declare that the led is OFF before the delay, the led will be always ON.

look at the two codes (the clock is 50MHz):

in this code the led is always ON.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
entity check is
port(clk : in std_logic;
      led : out std_logic);
end check;

architecture arc of check is
signal counter : integer range 0 to 100e6;
begin
process(clk)
begin
if rising_edge(clk) then
    if counter<500e6 then
        counter<=counter+1;
    else
        led<='1';
    end if;
end if;
end process;
end arc;
```

in this code the led is ON only after 20 seconds.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
entity check is
port(clk : in std_logic;
      led : out std_logic);
end check;

architecture arc of check is
signal counter : integer range 0 to 100e6;
begin
process(clk)
begin
if rising_edge(clk) then
    if counter<500e6 then
        counter<=counter+1;
        led<='0';
    else
        led<='1';
    end if;
end if;
end process;
end arc;
```

Comment: If that code works in simulation, the simulator is broken. It can never turn the LED on.

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize both counter and led. In simulation, when you don't do this, value of each uninitialized signal will be 'U', which means you simply cannot be sure what value it will have in real system. Can be both 0 or 1.
You can use := '0' in port declaration.

Probably led is always on, because according to this code, if counter<500e6, the value of 'led' doesn't matter and else it's 1, so compiler simplified it, because the only one value the program sets to 'led' is '1'.